# Bing Webmaster Tools SEO reports page says "No data available"

Tags: bing-webmaster-tools

I've had a Bing Webmaster Tools account for at least eight years. To date I have never seen a report on the SEO Reports page. I always get the "No data available".

My site has around 1500 pages covered by Bing Webmaster Tools so I doubt there's not enough data to produce a report.

Is this usual? If not, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are your pages actually indexed by Bing?

Comment: Yes. 2.1k indexed pages.

Answer (score 0):

The way it works is that you have to initiate scans.  Just under the `SEO Reports` menu is the `Site Scan` menu.

Go in there and create a scan.  It may take several hours to days before you see a report.

Comment: I have done 100s of scans over five or more years. No report yet.